# importing multiple json files into a js array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to having multiple `json` files imported to a `js` array

```
// module.js
module.exports={
    english:require("./englishfile"),
    chinese:require("./chineseFile"),
    french:require("./frenchFile"),
    spanish:require("./espFile"),
};
//js file
let allData=require("./module.js");
```

What this is doing is having all the files in a single array entry. I'm trying to have them as separate array entries for the entire size of `module.js` . I also would have a much larger number of files in `module.js` so I don't know its size and wouldn't be able to hard code them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
const requireModule = require.context('.',false,/\.json$/)
const modules = {}

requireModule.keys().forEach(filename => 
{
    const moduleName = fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.json)/g, '');
    modules[moduleName] = requireModule(fileName)

    OR

    modules[moduleName] = 
    {
        namespaced: true,
        ...requireModule(fileName)
    }
});

export default modules;
```